# JAX-ws connection pulling and thread safety

Tags: multithreading, web-services, jax-ws

I am integrating some JAX-WS ws calls with some legacy code, 
The legacy code creates a single instance of the class when it loads. (I will be implementing the web service calls in this single instance class).

Given this [sample JAX-WS usage code](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/README.html) :

```
Service calculatorService = Service.create(
        new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4204/Calculator?wsdl"),
        new QName("http://superbiz.org/wsdl", "CalculatorService"));

CalculatorWs calculator = calculatorService.getPort(CalculatorWs.class);
calculator.sum(4, 6));
```

As I understand [Service] is Thread safe While the proxy [CalculatorWs] is not thread safe is this correct?
What will be the correct way to handle multiple requests coming from the legacy system and making the web service calls?

Should I Create a connection pool to get existing [CalculatorWs] objects Or get both [CalculatorWs] object and [Service] object from the pool?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?) as your JAX-WS implementation, you can add this CXF-specific request context property to force it to be thread safe for outbound requests.  The documentation for CXF says the response context is automatically thread safe.

```
Service calculatorService = Service.create(
        new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4204/Calculator?wsdl"),
        new QName("http://superbiz.org/wsdl", "CalculatorService"));

CalculatorWs calculator = calculatorService.getPort(CalculatorWs.class);
//per CXF docs, custom request property ensures request context is threadsafe. Response context is already so.
((BindingProvider)calculator).getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context", "true");

calculator.sum(4, 6));
```

If you are using not using CXF (or wish to write portable code), you may need to use an object pool such as [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/)'s [GenericObjectPool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html) to reuse instances of `CalculatorWs`.

In this case you'll use an object factory and implement a subclass of [BasePooledObjectFactory](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/BasePooledObjectFactory.html) (`BasePooledObjectFactory<CalculatorWs>`, actually) which implements `create()` to use your `calculatorService.getPort(CalculatorWs.class)` call similar to [this example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/examples.html#A_PooledObjectFactory). It is the instance of `CalculatorWs` with which you need to be careful in known multithreaded scenarios.